# How to map a Python list to dictionary with all the same values?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-comprehension

I want to map a list `lst = ["a", "b", "c"]` to a dictionary that looks like `{"a": 1, "b": 1, "c": 1}`

What is the most Pythonic way for me to do that?

I currently have this:

```
converted_dict = {e: 1 for (e) in lst}
```

Comment: dict has a classmethod "fromkeys".

Comment: `Counter` class https://realpython.com/python-counter/